# How to resolve ORA-14257 when I modify partition table initial

Tags: oracle

I create a table with partition and sub partition,i want to modify partition initial and I got ORA-14257,how can I resolve this problem?

after I creating table , I spited partition and then got two partitions: test_table_partition1,test_table_pmaxvalue

```js
here is my Crete table sql:
create table test_table(
...
)compress for oltp
partition by range(column1)
subpartition by hash (column2)
subpartitions 32
(partition test_table_pmaxvalue values less than(maxvalue))
storage (initial 4M) tablespace "data" enable row movement;


here is my modify sql1 and I got ORA-14257:
 alter test_table move partition test_table_partition1
storage (initial 2M) tablespace "data";

here is my modify sql2 and I got ORA-02203:
 alter test_table modify partition test_table_partition1
    storage (initial 2M) tablespace "data";
```

Comment: you should move the sub-partitions first and then the partitions.
check this link https://tusharghotikar.wordpress.com/2016/01/18/ora-14257-cannot-move-partition-other-than-a-range-list-system-or-hash-partition/ , it has example to generate the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the partition and subpartition initial size when I splitting the partition by the sql:

```
alter table test_table split partition test_table_pmaxvalue at (20200524) into (partition test_table_P20200523 storage(initial xM),partition test_table_pmaxvalue)update indexes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its important to realise the difference between a logical and a physical partition. For example, with a table as per below

```
SQL> create table COMPOSITE
  2  ( tstamp       timestamp(6) not null,
  3    empno        number(10)   not null,
  4    ename        varchar2(10) not null,
  5    deptno       varchar2(10) not null
  6  )
  7  PARTITION BY RANGE (TSTAMP)
  8  SUBPARTITION BY LIST (deptno)
  9  (
 10    PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN
 11        (TIMESTAMP' 2018-01-01 00:00:00')
 12                 (SUBPARTITION p01_d1 VALUES (1),
 13                  SUBPARTITION p01_d2 VALUES (2),
 14                  SUBPARTITION p01_d3 VALUES (3),
 15                  SUBPARTITION p01_d4 VALUES (4)),
 16    PARTITION p2018 VALUES LESS THAN
 17        (TIMESTAMP' 2019-01-01 00:00:00')
 18                 (SUBPARTITION p02_d1 VALUES (1),
 19                  SUBPARTITION p02_d2 VALUES (2),
 20                  SUBPARTITION p02_d3 VALUES (3),
 21                  SUBPARTITION p02_d4 VALUES (4)),
       .....
 30    PARTITION p2019 VALUES LESS THAN
 31        (TIMESTAMP' 2020-01-01 00:00:00')
 32                 (SUBPARTITION p01_d1 VALUES (1,2),
 33                  SUBPARTITION p01_d2 VALUES (3,4),
 34    PARTITION p2020 VALUES LESS THAN
 35        (TIMESTAMP' 2021-01-01 00:00:00')
 36    PARTITION p2021
       .....
```

Then partition P2017 is *NOT* a physical segment, ie, it occupies no space on disk. This is because it has subpartitions. Those subpartitions are the physical segments on disk and the P2017 partition "parent" is just a logical construct indicating a group of 4 subpartitions.

Conversely, P2020 has no subpartitions so it will represent a genuine physical segment.

When it comes to moving partitions, you only move a partition that has a physical segment, thus you would not (and cannot) move P2017 because it doesn't contain anything (the subpartitions do).  However, you could move P2020 because it does.

So in your case it would be the subpartitions that you move.

Having said all of that, if the only reason you want to move a partition is to change the INITIAL extent, then don't bother.  Assuming its a locally managed tablespace with auto extent allocation (the default) then there is nothing to be gained from changing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I changed the partition INITIAL with the sql1 in case there are no subpatitions,is there a way to change the partition INITIAL in case there are subpatitions?

Comment: you need to move the subpartitions not the partitions, and to change the initial (which you don't need to do) then you can use the "modify defaults" clause